# Replace part of a string that matches a specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string-

```
vessel_type='##some_key##' AND vessel_name= '##other_key##'
```

I want it to be replaced with-

```
vessel_type='{$_POST['some_key']}' AND vessel_name='{$_POST['other_key']}'
```

This `some_key` and `other_key` can be any random text. How do I do that? Something like `preg_replace()` can help?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, something like `preg_replace` can help.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable by SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$_POST['pew'] = 'LOL!';
$str = 'i said ##pew##';
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('/##(\w+)##/', function($v) { return $_POST[$v[1]]; }, $str));
// string(11) "i said LOL!"
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't know the `pew` key?

Comment: And what do you know then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capturing group surrounded by `##` on either side:

```
$re = '/##([^#]+)##/'; 
$str = "vessel_type='##some_key##' AND vessel_name= '##other_key##'"; 
$subst = '{$_POST["$1"]}'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

//=> vessel_type='{$_POST["some_key"]}' AND vessel_name= '{$_POST["other_key"]}'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW3yM9/1)